# Paginationjs, handlebars, ajax call and JSON

Tags: json, ajax, handlebars.js

i'm trying to use paginationjs with a content loaded by AJAX.
here is the code

```
<div class="container container-fluid">

    <div id="review-container"></div>
    <div id="review-pagination"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/template" id="template-review">
    <div class="review__list">
    {{#each data}}
        {{state}}
        {{rate}}
    {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>

<script>
jQuery('#review-pagination').pagination({
    dataSource: function(done) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/reviews.json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                jQuery('#review-container').html('<?php echo $this->__("Récupération des avis..."); ?>');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                done(response);
            }
        });
    },
    locator: 'data',
    pageSize: 5,
    showPrevious: false,
    showNext: false,
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        console.log("===> "+typeof(data));
        console.log(data);
        //var data = JSON.stringify({ data: data });
        var html = Handlebars.compile(jQuery('#template-review').html(), {
            data: data
        });
        jQuery('#review-container').html(html);
    }
})
</script>
```

No matter the dataSource type (URL, function), it seems that handlebars can't loop in the {{#each}}

Here is the result of the two console.log in the callback

```
:1790 ===> object
:1791 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {state: "4", rate: "4", canal: "online", id_review: "eb53a2a3-09aa-42e4-b475-6233383ee634", order_ref: "100246459", …}
1: {state: "4", rate: "5", canal: "online", id_review: "cb581889-2439-4e43-b36b-dbfdc5ae1139", order_ref: "100244923", …}
2: {state: "4", rate: "4", canal: "online", id_review: "77506f2f-9b77-41a3-9e4c-37b477c943ce", order_ref: "100250211", …}
3: {state: "4", rate: "5", canal: "online", id_review: "de85eba0-4e84-4c47-915c-5fdf0157eb5b", order_ref: "100249780", …}
4: {state: "4", rate: "5", canal: "online", id_review: "b77f6a0f-9dd8-47cd-ad73-4bff3150e832", order_ref: "100251412", …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The pagination is well generated, but all the content (from json) is missing. As if it is empty.

Someone for some help please ?

Comment: Edited, sorry ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use the result of calling `Handlebars.compile` as if it were a string of HTML, but `Handlebars.compile` returns a Function, not a String.

There are really two parts to using Handlebars:

1. Compile your template into a template function.
2. Call your template function with your context data.

You are trying to combine these two steps into one by passing the context data to the `Handlebars.compile` call, but this will not work. You need to do the compilation before executing the template function.

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(jQuery('#template-review').html());
var html = template({
    data: data
});
jQuery('#review-container').html(html);
```

Additionally, it would be wise to move the compilation *out* of the `callback` function because you do not need to compile the template more than once (the compiled template function does not change, only the context value it is called with changes).

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/603jLn8u/) for your reference.